# Is a Descriptor* and FieldDescriptor* fine to re-use for different instances of a derived Message?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

In the C++ api docs for protocol buffers, and spcifically the Message::GetDescriptor method, there is this description:

https://protobuf.dev/reference/cpp/api-docs/google.protobuf.message/#Message.GetDescriptor.details

> const Descriptor *
> Message::GetDescriptor() const Get a non-owning pointer to a Descriptor for this message's type.
>
> This describes what fields the message contains, the types of those
> fields, etc. This object remains property of the Message.

Since getting the Descrtiptor pointer from a Message instance is quite a slow process, I want to store Descriptor and FieldDescriptor pointers for my common Reflection operations and re-use them when handling different instances of a derived Message. I'm doing this right now and it seems to be working fine, but then there is that last sentence; "This object remains property of the Message".

What does that mean exactly? I can interpret it as the Descriptor object behind the Descriptor pointer retrieved by calling GetDescriptor() on a Message instance is only valid for as long as that derived Message object lives. This doesn't seem right, but what else can that formulation mean?

Notice that they use the same formulation for the GetReflection method and also for that case I would guess that the pointer can be re-used later on a different Message object, since the object is passed with any calls to manipulate or read from it.

I want to confirm that the Descriptor pointer retrieved by calling Message::GetDescriptor() is not depending on any particular instance of the derived Message instance, but is fine to store and re-use later when all Message instances have been deleted.